# Laravel telescope dose not show request details

Tags: laravel, laravel-telescope

Laravel telescope was showing details tab in version laravel/telescope: ^4.9

[image]

but version "laravel/telescope": "^4.17" dose not show it but works

[image]
I do not know if there is new configurations to show it but I tried with config file without results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with 4.17 after they migrated from mix to vite.

For now, you can use 4.16.4 instead of 4.17. Migration from mix to vite is the only difference between these two versions.

run `composer require "laravel/telescope=4.16.4"` to install the older version.

**Update:**

Ok, Laravel release a newer which is 4.17.2, and it's the same as 4.16.4. Actually, they reverted the migration form mix to vite.

You can update the package to this newer version or use the 4.16.4.